# Get Alert when a NuGet package gets updated?

Tags: c#, .net, automation, nuget, devops

As a part of DevOps team we have to automate a certain workflow.

Our development team is at the liberty to update the NuGet package reference whenever it is required however the same updated library needs to be integrated in our msi installer as well as CI build steps. If a developer forgets to inform the build team then we face issues when his code gets merged.

How can I trigger a workflow/alert which can let us know that a reference (NuGet or normal assembly reference) has been updated?

StackOverflow Noobie.

Comment: I would think your CI Build would fail - I know that's not the nicest form of alerting, but it should catch the breaking code as it's being checked in. You could then alert the developer and the build team in response to the CI Build failure.

Comment: You should look into using Dependabot. It's like a cron job that will submit PRs with updated dependencies. Nuget doesn't support webhooks from the looks of it so you need a cron to watch for changes.

Comment: @h0r53 Thanks for the idea. We do we have compilation and warning analysis automation as the code checks in via PRs. The thing is that a NuGet/Assembly reference update does not break compilation. It breaks the build part where we process output and wrap in installer. The build part takes time and is not included in pr automation.